# How to have c# match a hashed password in my mysql database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, authentication

I have an existing web site running IPS/Invision Community. I am creating a companion C# application that will share the same database and authentication.

Looking in the database for the existing site, I can see it follows good practice and stores passwords as hashes, rather than plain-text. An example hash value looks like this:

```
$2y$10$Tu9ImODbXvVVtievNhkEIODyonQgclnDXQ.8N8mRPd2JMQYSDStqK
```

I need my C# code to be able to duplicate this hashing process, so my companion app can authenticate users.

I found this PHP code in the original web site:

```
public function getUniqueMemberHash()
{
    /* If this is a guest, just return a random string. */
    if ( !$this->member_id )
    {
        return \IPS\Login::generateRandomString();
    }
    
    /* Return the password hash if we already have it */
    if ( !empty( $this->members_pass_hash ) )
    {
        return md5( ( $this->members_pass_hash ?: $this->email ) . $this->members_pass_salt );
    }

    /* Do we already have one? */
    if ( !empty( $this->unique_hash ) )
    {
        return $this->unique_hash;
    }

    /* Otherwise, generate one */
    $this->unique_hash = md5( \IPS\Login::generateRandomString(32) );

    $this->save();

    return $this->unique_hash;
}


 /* Compare hashes in fixed length, time constant manner.
 *
 * @param   string  $expected   The expected hash
 * @param   string  $provided   The provided input
 * @return  boolean
 */
public static function compareHashes( $expected, $provided )
{
    // *0 and *1 are failures from crypt() - if we have ended up with an invalid hash anywhere, we will reject it to prevent a possible vulnerability from deliberately generating invalid hashes
    if ( !\is_string( $expected ) || !\is_string( $provided ) || $expected === '*0' || $expected === '*1' || $provided === '*0' || $provided === '*1' ) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $len = \strlen( $expected );
    if ( $len !== \strlen( $provided ) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $status = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ )
    {
        $status |= \ord( $expected[ $i ] ) ^ \ord( $provided[ $i ] );
    }
    
    return $status === 0;
}

/**
 * Return a random string
 *
 * @param   int     $length     The length of the final string
 * @return  string
 */
public static function generateRandomString( $length=32 )
{
    $return = '';

    if ( \function_exists( 'random_bytes' ) )
    {
        $return = \substr( bin2hex( random_bytes( $length ) ), 0, $length );
    }
    elseif( \function_exists( 'openssl_random_pseudo_bytes' ) )
    {
        $return = \substr( bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( ceil( $length / 2 ) ) ), 0, $length );
    }

    /* Fallback JUST IN CASE */
    if( !$return OR \strlen( $return ) != $length )
    {
        $return = \substr( md5( uniqid( '', true ) ) . md5( uniqid( '', true ) ), 0, $length );
    }

    return $return;
}

public static function compareHashes( $expected, $provided )
{
    // *0 and *1 are failures from crypt() - if we have ended up with an invalid hash anywhere, we will reject it to prevent a possible vulnerability from deliberately generating invalid hashes
    if ( !\is_string( $expected ) || !\is_string( $provided ) || $expected === '*0' || $expected === '*1' || $provided === '*0' || $provided === '*1' ) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $len = \strlen( $expected );
    if ( $len !== \strlen( $provided ) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $status = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ )
    {
        $status |= \ord( $expected[ $i ] ) ^ \ord( $provided[ $i ] );
    }
    
    return $status === 0;
}
```

My companion app so far has this C# code to retrieve a user record, but of course it does not work yet because I don't know what to do for the `HashPassword()` method:

```
string server = "s570.use8.mysecurecloudhost.com";
string database = "nextgene_NGH";
string uid = "nextgene_NGH";
string password = "EXAMPLE PASSWORD";
string ssl = "None";

string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";

// NEVER NEVER NEVER store an "exact password" in a database!!
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM `core_members` where name= @name AND hashed_password= @hash;";
var dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(SQL, connection))
    using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        //NEVER NEVER NEVER use string concatenation to put user input in a query
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  maskedTextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", HashPassword(maskedTextBox2.Text));
  
        da.Fill(dt); //Fill opens and closes the connection
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.");
        //button2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

How can I make this C# code correctly authenticate the user?

Comment: You need to use the same code that hashes the password when you insert the user. Apply that code to your clear text password and pass the result as parameter

Comment: Using plain text for the password is not supposed to work. NEVER store plain-text passwords. Also, posting images of technical information like code and sample data, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code as _text_, not a screenshot. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have tried your possible answer and it came out not working as intended, I should have access to the module that hashed it and so I am looking for it now.

Comment: @RyanEllis I'm not exactly sure what `getUniqueMemberHash` is doing, but it may not be used to create the `members_pass_hash` because it uses it as input. Does the PHP code use `password_hash` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php anywhere? That's likely to be the PHP method used to create password hashes. If so, what options are provided to that function?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have posted more code below the photos for you... I hope that can answer your question. I also did a regex search and I do not think they use that function with that name but rather with the name: members_pass_hash

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have seen you post on several of my questions. Your code below, is throwing an cannot convert from object to string after the maskedtextbox2.text

Comment: @RyanEllis You are correct. I just added the missing `(string)` cast to `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: and finally, @BradleyGrainger i am not sure but now even after adding the cast, it is giving me the System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' which then you saw in the other question I had asked.

Comment: @RyanEllis I re-tested the code and it works fine for me. As per that other question, you'll need to debug the code to find out exactly where the `NullReferenceException` is coming from.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger can you please point me to a good video reference? Again, I am new to programming and never needed to debug the code.

Comment: @RyanEllis I've never actually used any video tutorials on debugging (or C#) so I don't have a good one to recommend, sorry.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I was able to see but what the issue is where ***var hashedPassword***; this returns null

Comment: That means that the SQL command found no rows that matched; i.e., there's no row in `core_members` where `name` is equal to `maskedTextBox1.Text`.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger but there is... here is a snippet of my database... https://ibb.co/JKmTwRk

Answer (score 3):

`$2y$10$` at the beginning of the hashed password is an almost-certain indicator that the hashes are computed with a variant of the [bcrypt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), most likely [`password_hash` in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). You can generate and verify these in C# by using the [BCrypt.Net-Next](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next) NuGet package.

For example, I went to https://phppasswordhash.com/, entered `Passw0rd` and was given the hashed string `$2y$10$Tu9ImODbXvVVtievNhkEIODyonQgclnDXQ.8N8mRPd2JMQYSDStqK`. (Note that the algorithm uses a random salt, so you will get a different string every time.) Then I verified the password in C# by running `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify("Passw0rd", "$2y$10$Tu9ImODbXvVVtievNhkEIODyonQgclnDXQ.8N8mRPd2JMQYSDStqK")`, which returned `true`.

You can't pass the hash as a parameter to a MySQL statement, because you don't know what the salt is. Instead, retrieve the hashed password from the database and verify it:

```cs
using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE name = @name;", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
var hashedPassword = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();

if (hashedPassword is not null && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
}
```